# Создание экземпляра класса из литерала в typescript

Tags: typescript

Я имею литеральный объект, возвращаемый сервером и задача состоит в том, чтобы преобразовать его в экземпляр конкретно класса. К примеру сервер возвращает:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "id": "name",
            "message": "Such name is already exists"             
        },
        {
            "id": "name",
            "message": "You cannot use numbers"             
        }
    ]
}
```

И допустим у меня есть Класс:

```
class Error {
    id: number;
    message: string;
}
class Errors {
    "errors": Array<Error>;
}
```

Здесь пример конечно утрированный, в реальности объект гораздо сложнее. 
Пытался сделать это с помощью миксины: добавить в класс статический метод `castLiteral`, который будет создавать объект своего класса, проходиться по литералу и заполнять этот объект, однако в таком случае не знаю как быть с полями объектного типа, как понять какой у них тип и имеет ли этот тип метод `castLiteral`? Хотя все же надеюсь что уже есть какое-нибудь готовое решение или подход.